# Why proton and neutron in an atom don't spread out like electron cloud?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, neutrons, protons

Proton and neutron are very tiny particles and should follow the heisenberg uncertainty principle and spread out like the electron cloud, which also apply to the quarks that made up the proton and neutron?

Comment: They do. Atomic nuclei have nucleonic orbital states just like the electron cloud. The difference is mainly the interaction strength  and form.

Comment: Also the strong interaction is short-ranged and manifests anti-screening effect. The valence quarks are bound into hadrons. The radius of a hadron is given by its distribution of color charge.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Nuclear shell model https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model It is very similar to the atomic shell model. The protons and neutrons arrange in shells and the energy levels become significantly lower as each shell is filled. They called those the magic numbers. I think it’s even more interesting than electron arrangements.